# How to orient the protein for lipid bilayer simulation in Gromacs

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, membranes

I was trying to perform an MD of a protein (Mrgprx2) in a lipid bilayer.

The domain of the protein looks like this:

[image]

Thus I'd like to have the transmembrane part of the protein to be buried in lipid membrane,
and the extracellular part of it to be placed outside membrane.

I was following the **[Gromacs Membrane Protein Tutorial](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/membrane_protein/index.html)**.

However the protein orientation I get is not as I expected:

[image]

Notice that the whole protein is buried in the lipid and in tilted position instead of perpendicular with respect to the lipid bilayer.
How can I properly orient the protein in the membrane?

G.V.

Comment: Did you get the tilted position AFTER running the simulation?

Comment: @Camps no, I haven't run the MD `gmx mdrun -deffnm md_0_1`.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Step One: Prepare the Topology](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/membrane_protein/01_pdb2gmx.html), second paragraph, you can find the following information:

> The peptide was prepared in-house using the xLeap module of
> AmberTools, using ideal backbone geometry of an α-helix (φ = -60°, ψ =
> -40°). The .pdb file was oriented along the z-axis using editconf -princ, followed by a rotation about the y axis. Note that in GROMACS-3.3.x, the -princ option oriented the long axis of the
> structure (in this case, the helix axis) along the z-axis by default,
> but this option has changed as of GROMACS-4.0.4, which orients the
> long axis along the x-axis. If you want to skip the construction of
> this peptide, the properly oriented structure can be found here.

I think that before setting up your system, you can prepare (rotate) your protein and use it in the orientation you want.

Comment: Beautiful! I had bookmarked this question out of keen interest! My background as an undergrad was largely in biology, and now I wish I could answer questions like these! Maybe we need to do more computational biochemistry papers :)

Answer (score 3):

I used [VMD to re-orient the protein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-iyn88b830) in combination with `editconf` rotation:

`gmx editconf -f myprotein_processed.gro -rotate 0 90 0  -o myprotein_newbox.gro -c -box 6.41840 6.44350 6.59650`

It worked.

The final result I got is this:

[image]